# Hard drive and power consumption of current Time Capsule

Tags: time-capsule

What kind of hard drive is build into the current Time Capsule? Is it a SSD? Also, how energy efficient is the current Time Capsule, how much energy does it consume? I can't find this info on Apples product pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a 2TB or 3TB storage you can be sure it's HDD, since the price is 'only' 299$ or 399$. There are for the moment no (commercial) 2TB SSD drives or maybe one or two which are really really expensive. On the product page is also stated that the Time capsule is ussing a Hard drive, otherwise there would be stated Soild State drive or similar.

The enviromental report, including energy usage can be found here: https://www.apple.com/environment/reports/docs/AirPortTimeCapsule_PER_feb2014.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When in use, apple states it uses 11watts at 115 volts. The power supply is 88 percent efficient according to apple. These figures refer to the now current (december 2014) version of time capsule and apply to both the 2gb and 3gb model